# Can someone explain this Binary search tree height function to me?

Tags: tree, height, binary-search-tree

So I've been looking at this function and it makes no sense to me.

```
int findHeight(BinaryNode<E> aNode)
{
    if(aNode ==null){
          return -1;
    }


    int lefth = findHeight(aNode.left);
    int righth = findHeight(aNode.right);

    if(lefth > righth)
        return lefth + 1;
    else
        return righth +1;
}
```

Lets say I have a tree that consists of 1 root who has one left child only. So root->LeftChild.

We run this method.
root isnt null so we continue to int lefth=...
When we get to int Lefth we run the same method again but with the left child as paramter.
leftchild is not null so we continue to int lefth=...
but the child does not have any childs so what happens? I dont understand it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive function (it calls itself).  To understand how it works, you first have to visualize what it does.

First, think of every BinaryNode as the root of a new subtree.  You can call `findHeight` on any node in the tree, and it will return the height of that subtree.

As the function executes, it calls itself to find the height of every left and right node in the subtree.  As long as that node is not `null` (indicating the leaf of a tree), it will continue travelling down a branch until it does reach a node that  is null, at which point it will `return` a value of -1 (because the null node doesn't count as part of the tree's height).

Then, it will begin `return`ing back up the tree to the root node.  As it returns from each node in the branch, it adds 1 to the returned value.  When it gets to the top, what will be returned is the sum of all the heights in the *longest branch* (which is why the `if` statement is there).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually `aNode.left` will become `null` in a tree so the recursion will stop.

At this point the stack of recursions (`findHeight root -> findHeight root.left -> findHeight root.left.left [null]`) will be resolved to a number.

The "final" evaluation will be something like this

`-1 [null] + 1 [root.left] + 1 [root] = 1`

So the height would be 1 (which is correct for only one left child of the root, nothing more)

For simplicity I left the if/else out of this example.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call the method on the "child" of a leaf node, which is null, you hit the first if statement and return -1. You then add 1 in every recursive call on the stack, including 1 for the non-existant null child. Therefore the method returns the height.